# Simple question about number theory in CLRS book

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

This is theorem 11.5 from CLRS book.
Suppose $a\in \mathbb{Z}^*_p, b\in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Consider two distinct keys $k$ and $l$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so that $k \neq l$. For a given
hash function $h_{ab}$ we let
$$r =ak +b\mod p $$
$$s =al +b\mod p $$
We first note that $r \neq s$. Why? Observe that
$$r-  s \equiv a(k-l) \pmod p. $$

I'm not very well familiar with Number Theory, so my question is why
$$r-  s \equiv a(k-l) \pmod p $$
is correct?

Comment: If $r=ak+b$ mod $p$ and $s=al+b$ mod $p$, then $r-s=(ak+b)-(al+b)=a(k-l)$ mod $p$.

Comment: @Mindlack Probably even best as a solution rather than a comment.

Comment: I can't understand where is $\mod p $ in $ (ak+b)-(al+b)$?

Comment: Mabe you removed it because negative symbol has no effect on module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Everything @Mindlack said**, plus some explanations, since the fact that *you said you are not so familiar with Number Theory*.

---

According to [Knuth's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#cite_note-4) for the $\bmod{}$ operation, we have

\begin{align*}
a \bmod{} n = a-n \lfloor{}\frac{a}{n}\rfloor{}
\end{align*}

And with the general definition of [Congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence), $a \equiv{} b \pmod{n}$ can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
a-b=kn
\end{align*}

We then have
\begin{align*}
r &= ak+b \bmod{p} = ak+b - p \lfloor{}\frac{ak+b}{p}\rfloor{} \\
s &= al+b \bmod{p} = al+b - p \lfloor{}\frac{al+b}{p}\rfloor{} 
\end{align*}
Subtract $r$ by $s$, we have

\begin{align*}
r-s = a(k-l) - p \left( \lfloor{}\frac{ak+b}{p}\rfloor{} + \lfloor{}\frac{al+b}{p}\rfloor{} \right) \tag{A}
\end{align*}

With the definition of congruence quoted above, we can then rewrite (A) as
\begin{align*}
r-s \equiv{} a(k-l) \pmod{p}
\end{align*}

Hope this eliminates your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I’m turning my comment into an answer. If $r=ak+b$ mod $p$, and $s=al+b$ mod $p$, then $r-s=(ak+b)-(al+b)$ mod $p$, thus $r-s=ak-al$ mod $p$, hence $r-s=a(k-l)$ mod $p$.